# Dynamically generating image source angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to choose the source of an image dynamically using angular JS as follows:

```
<img star-video src="[[getStar(vid.videoId)]]" >
```

The image is not showing and upon inspecting dev tools I that the src attribute is not even showing. In my controller I am generating the links as follows **using getStar()**:

```
.controller("rightNavController", ["$scope", function($scope) {      

  $scope.getVidLink = function(vidID){
    return "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID + "?autoplay=0&controls=0";
  };

  var inactive = "http://local/path/to/img/star_inactive.png";
  var active = "http://local/path/to/img/star_active.png";

  $scope.getStar = function(videoID){
    jq.each($scope.$root.starredVids, function(){
      if(this.videoID === videoID){
        return active;
      } else{
        return inactive;
      }
    });
  };
}])
```

However when I try to generate a youtube link using similar method it works, using **getVidLink()**

Can you please help me understand why its working on the **iframe** for youtube but not on the **img** element. If there is a better way of doing this, can you please advice.

Comment: you need to provide `src` as `ng-src` and you have to put it in angular syntax `{{getStar(vid.videoId)}}`

Comment: Even when I use ng-src it does not work. I am using angular and django so to avoid conflict with django template I had to use interpolate so I can use [[ ]] instead of {{ }}

Comment: @DHRUVGUPTA excuse me that was a typo here. I edited it

Comment: No @DHRUVGUPTA . The links represented by **active** and **inactive** point to images. What I am saying is that when I add a link pointing to a video into an iframe it works, but does not work when I use a similar technique on an image.